# Como abrir arquivos html diretamente do visual studio para o meu navegador padrão?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Utilizo o visual studio code no Ubuntu, e gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de abrir um arquivo html com apenas um clique para meu navegador padrão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aperte ctrl+ shift+ p(ou F1) para abrir a paleta de comandos.

Digite Tasks - **Configure Task** nas versões mais antigas **Configure Task Runner**. Ao selecionar, o arquivo tasks.json será aberto . Exclua o script exibido e substitui pelo outro:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "explorer",    
    "windows": {
        "command": "explorer.exe"
    },
    "args": ["test.html"]
}
```

**E tem também essa extensão**

> **Live Server Preview**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

## Open in browser - Basta você adicionar está extensão no seu visual Studio. Espero ter ajudado!

**Segue imagens.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: essa extensão não funciona no meu OS :/

Answer (score -3):

Tem um extensão da microsoft chamada Live Preview olha só como fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode add ela aqui > https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).